# sequence of diophantine approximants of $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, pi, diophantine-approximation

I define the sequence of optimal diophantine approximants of $\pi$ to be the sequence $u_m = \frac{n}{m}$ where $n$ is given by $\min_{\forall n \in \mathbb{N}} |\frac{n}{m}-\pi|$ and we define $\epsilon(m):=\min_{\forall n \in \mathbb{N}} |\frac{n}{m}-\pi|$.

From calculations I have done I think it's reasonable to conjecture that for $m \geq 4, \epsilon(m)\leq \frac{\epsilon(4)}{C^{m-4}}$ where $C \geq \frac{3}{2}$. But, I think it's possible to find a larger value for $C$.

Is there a much better bound on $C$ than what I found?

Comment: Did you have a look at the (simple) continued fraction convergents of $\pi$?

Comment: My interest is not limited to the behavior of sequences with particular denominators. I think my question concerns more than a particular continued fraction convergent of $\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) of $\pi$ is less than $8$. This means that
$$
\Bigl|\pi-\frac{n}{m}\Bigr|>\frac{1}{m^8}
$$
for all $n$ and all $m$ suficiente large. Thus, for $m$ large enough,
$$
\epsilon(m)\ge\frac{1}{m^8}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What about the upper-bound on $\epsilon(m)$?

Comment: Let $\mu$ be the irrationality measure of $\pi$. Then $\epsilon(m)\le C/m^\mu$.